# Random spacing in table with div inside

Tags: html, css, html-table, mybb

Here is the problem:
http://www.welivetech.net/showthread.php?tid=46

As you can see the text is all in random places to the right. It has nothing to do with the length of the username as "dynamic" posted all of the posts.

Does anyone know of any solution to this? It's been driving me crazy since yesterday..

There is nothing with PHP screwing this up, it's somewhere in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the width of the first `<td>` (the one with the user picture). Otherwise, both cells are getting dynamically sized, depending on the proportion of the width of the contents in each. Add `width: 160px` to it and viola is just like violin, but larger.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. Never would have thought of that. Also, very punny.